# How to plot a circle in Matlab? (least square)

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot a circle's equation-regression on x and y, but I do not know how to proceed. Any suggestions? (I want a circle to connect the points thru least square solution)

```
x = [5; 4; -1; 1];
y = [3; 5; 2; 1];

% circle's equation: x^2+y^2 = 2xc1+2yc2+c3
a = [2.*x,2.*y,ones(n,3)]
b = [x.^2 + y.^2];
c = a\b;
```

How do I plot the circle after this

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/495938-least-square-circle-why-doesn-t-it-work#answer_405783)?

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of ways how to plot a circle in matlab:

- plot a line where the data points form a circle
- use the `'o'` [marker](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linespec.html) in plot and the `'MarkerSize'` name-value pair to set the radius of the circle
- you can plot a circle image using the `vscircle` [function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/viscircles.html?searchHighlight=viscircles&s_tid=doc_srchtitle)
  In your case, I would go with the first option, since you maintain in control of the circle size.
- use the `rectangle(...,'Curvature',[1 1])` [function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rectangle.html?s_tid=doc_ta) [EDITED: thx to @Cris Luengo]

So here is a plotting function

```
function circle(x,y,r)
%x and y are the coordinates of the center of the circle
%r is the radius of the circle
%0.01 is the angle step, bigger values will draw the circle faster but
%you might notice imperfections (not very smooth)
ang=0:0.01:2*pi+.01; 
xp=r*cos(ang);
yp=r*sin(ang);

plot(x+xp,y+yp);
end
```

So with your (corrected) code, it looks like this

```
x = [5; 4; -1; 1];
y = [3; 5; 2; 1];

% circle's equation:  x^2+y^2 = 2xc1+2yc2+c3
a = [2.*x,2.*y,ones(length(x),1)];
b = [x.^2 + y.^2];
c = a\b;

x_m = c(1)/2;
y_m = c(2)/2;
r = sqrt(x_m^2 + y_m^2 -c(3));

% plot data points
plot(x,y,'o')
hold on
% plot center
plot(x_m,y_m,'+')
% plot circle
circle(x_m,y_m,r)
hold off
```

[image: matlab plot]

Comment: Yet another way: use the `rectangle` function with the `curvature` value set to 1. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rectangle.html#busqhee-1